# How to prepare my own data set for the DCP training?

Tags: python, pytorch, hdf5, point-clouds

I have ply files to be used for training in DCP(deep closest point). Data format is hdf5 for DCP Training.  The Data Format contains the following information: Data, FaceId, Normal, Label... But Ply file just  have Datas(x y z).
how can i do this transformation?

Comment: To get some help, you need to provide more details. For example you described the DCP data format and the Ply file datasets. But it's not clear to me (and likely others), how the data are related. How does Data, FaceId, Normal, Label...map to (x, y, z)??

Comment: In fact, I am trying to learn the relationship between them.